# How to monitor Google App Engine Queue size over time?

Tags: google-app-engine, monitoring, task-queue

The Google App Engine developer console allows you to easier monitor instantaneous queue size for an app. How can you simply view queue size over time?

For context: the backend process off our application runs through a fairly restrictive queue, as front end availability is a priority (and it's currently a free app). What I'd like to monitor is the size of the task queue over time which would give me a good proxy of the backlog of work.

I could set up a process just to log this directly, and then a separate page to the graph it, however this seems a little involved for something that may be already easily available either as a graph, or at least a queriable data-series direct from the app engine.

Comment: Good question. Are you using a Pull or Push queue?  I think you will have to roll your own using QueueStatistics [[Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queue_statistics) | [javadoc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/QueueStatistics)] but it might be handy to have this sort of metric in [Cloud Monitoring](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/). You could use some memcache counters each time you execute the task queue handler if you don't need durable data.

Comment: I'm using a Push Queue at the moment, two of them. One which is higher priority than the other. The high priority one shouldn't usually have a backlog. The Low priority one, should have a backlog, and the size of it is exactly what I'd like to monitor. I like the idea of having it in Cloud Monitoring, what's the best way of making that happen? Is it something I can do myself or is it something should spam a request form for? ;P

Comment: There's a Cloud Monitoring API which allows you to provide [custom metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/). Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @tx802 for help with this answer:

It's not currently simple to view these metrics. The process to setting them up however is:

1. Set up a simple CRON job to read the [QueueStatistics](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/queue_statistics#QueueStatistics_tasks) object for the given queue on whatever time basis is interesting (I chose every 5 minutes).
2. Use the [Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/) function to store the value as a custom metric which you can then pull up in the Cloud Monitoring Dashboard.